# searchControl и поиск по организациям

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы вот эта подсказка по организациям была открыта постоянно, а не только когда есть фокус у searchControl

Answer (score 2):

Это рубричный-саджест и его не получится использовать отдельно от контрола поиска или выводить без фокуса в поле ввода.

Вы можете сделать собственную панель с рубриками, через кастомный элемент управления через [интерфейс `IControl`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IControl-docpage/?from=SO). Вот [пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_control?from=SO) как отправная точка, с которой можно начать разбираться.

P.S. Обратите внимание, что в панели стоит использовать [HTTP Геопоиска](http://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch?from=SO) (Поиска по организациям), потому что поиск по организациям в JS API запрещено видоизменять.

Comment: Извините,  вы можете гарантировать, что ссылка с примером не будет перемещена или удалена? Может стоит опубликовать код примера прямо в ответе.

Comment: Могу)) Код примера в ответе в данном случае не поможет, потому что надо либо написать всё за пользователя, либо это просто базовая фича из API, описанная в документации. Пример тут как точка, с которой начать разбираться.

Comment: @0xdb зачем вы добавили неправильный код в ответ?( не думаю, что это делает решение понятнее

Comment: Код из ссылки, которую вы дали. Уберите ссылку из ответа, если от опубликованного там кода никакой пользы.

Comment: @0xdbя не вижу смысла спорить) код в примере правильный, но вы его скопировали некорректно, например, в песочнице Яндекса код скрипта лежит в отдельном js файле из-за этого ваша копипаста кидает ошибки, что не может его найти. Не  думаю, что это лучше поможет человеку, чем ссылка на официальную документацию, которая никуда не денется.

Comment: Сделайте правильно.